# println error when printing bytes

Tags: java

I have wrote the simple program below to output hello in arabic language :"سلام" but it's output on console is not correct:

```
import static java.lang.Integer.toBinaryString;

import java.util.Arrays;


public class testOfPrintln {
    public static void main(String []strings){
        String test="salam";
        String test2="سلام";//unicode , arabic
        byte []strbytes=test.getBytes();
        int i=1;
        for(byte bb:strbytes)
            System.out.println(i++  + "    -> " + bb);
        byte []strbytes2=test2.getBytes();
        i=1;
        for(byte bb2:strbytes2){
            System.out.println(i++  + "    ->   " + bb2);
        }
    }

}
```

and output:

```
1    -> 115
2    -> 97
3    -> 108
4    -> 97
5    -> 109
1    -> -40
2    -> -77
3    -> -39
4    -> -124
5    -> -40
6    -> -89
7    -> -39
8    -> -123
```

why there is a "-" character before bytes? for example:  -123
tnx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Java `byte` is a *signed* integer with values ranging from -128 to 127. If you want *unsigned* values, cast to `int` (happens implicitly when ANDing) and AND with 255.

```
System.out.println(i++  + "    -> " + (bb & 0xff));
```

Comment: Adding 128 is wrong. Although the result will be in the range 0 to 255, all the numbers will have a different representation, and `((byte)(bb + 128)) != bb`. The correct way is to 'and' it.

Answer (score 1):

The designers of Java made the `byte` type *signed*, even though that's not what anyone wants 99% of the time. So its range is -128 to +127 instead of 0 to 255. To get the proper value, and it with 0xFF (which in binary, is eight 1 bits). (The Java rules on [binary numeric promotion](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.6.2) say that the result of this expression will be of type `int`, which is why the 0 to 255 result fits, without being squashed back into a byte and becoming negative again.):

```
System.out.println(i++  + "    ->   " + (bb2 & 0xFF));
```